# Use machine learning to classify documents based on relevance with Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm developing an application to search several news sources for a keyword and return a database of links sorted by relevance to the keyword. However, I have hit a wall. Is it possible to have a training set with several articles being confirmed relevant to a certain keyword (and have a good amount of different keywords) and then of course some that are confirmed not relevant, and train that classifier to work on keywords & articles with a **keyword that has not been trained?** Like if I have a training set of relevant articles about dogs, relevant articles about cats, relevant articles about fish, and then try that classifier on an article about construction, could I theoretically get an accurate answer? [Here's the link to my project if anyone is interested](https://github.com/calthecoder/StoryGrab)

Comment: Yes..theoretically you can

Comment: @RahulAgarwal how? Is there a tutorial you could point me to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want your system to come up with tags that you haven't pre-defined, then you should probably look at an unsupervised approach. Google groups their news articles into topics for the day using clustering algorithms, i.e, it isn't trained on a list of keywords. Why don't you try LDA and see if you get meaningful results? Here's a python library to help. https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel

Also consider whether you need the labels or if you just need to group the documents. If you just need to group the documents then ordinary clustering will do fine.

If you have some labels that you are training on then you can do a hybrid approach.